# Fishbowl Part Average Cost API

Tags: api, fishbowl

I am facing issue with Fishbowl Part Average Cost API "https://www.fishbowlinventory.com/wiki/Fishbowl_Legacy_API#Part_Cost".

Previously If we request for multiple part in one API call then in response we got the all the parts response in single time. But in new update from Fishbowl API right now I am getting only one part response if I request for the multiple part in one call.

Previously API behave like this :

Request:

```
<FbiXml>
    <Ticket>
        <Key>HQZzIeyCYndxauMpHaCdlg==</Key>
    </Ticket>
    <FbiMsgsRq>
        <PartCostRq>
            <PartNum>B202</PartNum>
        </PartCostRq>
        <PartCostRq>
            <PartNum>B203</PartNum>
        </PartCostRq>
   <PartCostRq>
            <PartNum>B204</PartNum>
        </PartCostRq>
    </FbiMsgsRq>
</FbiXml>
```

In response :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FbiXml>
    <Ticket>
        <UserID>11</UserID>
        <Key>HQZzIeyCYndxauMpHaCdlg==</Key>
    </Ticket>
    <FbiMsgsRs statusCode="1000">
        <PartCostRs statusCode="1000">
            <PartNum>B202</PartNum>
            <Cost>11</Cost>
        </PartCostRs>
        <PartCostRs statusCode="1000">
            <PartNum>B203</PartNum>
            <Cost>12</Cost>
        </PartCostRs>
        <PartCostRs statusCode="1000">
            <PartNum>B204</PartNum>
            <Cost>120.01</Cost>
        </PartCostRs>
    </FbiMsgsRs>
</FbiXml>
```

Currently it's behavior in response :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FbiXml>
    <Ticket>
        <UserID>11</UserID>
        <Key>HQZzIeyCYndxauMpHaCdlg==</Key>
    </Ticket>
    <FbiMsgsRs statusCode="1000">
        <PartCostRs statusCode="1000">
            <PartNum>B202</PartNum>
            <Cost>11</Cost>
        </PartCostRs>
    </FbiMsgsRs>
</FbiXml>
```

I need all the part average cost in one API call. Please suggest me if any other API is available or any suggestions.

Comment: This was a change to help server stability. The ability to chain API calls within a single request was removed in version 2018.8. The best solution to help maintain the server stability is to execute each request individually.

Comment: @Mamof Is there any other API which provide me multiple part average cost in single response ?

Comment: There is not. In order to address stability issues the Fishbowl API now only allows a single request per call. If you need to run many results the only other option would be using the ExecuteQueryRq and writing a query to get the data for all the parts at once.

Comment: @Mamof Thank you